# How to detect last test from TestCase in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

I can easily detect first test:

```
public static $databaseMigrated = false;

protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    if (TestCase::$databaseMigrated === false) {
           $this->migrateDatabase();
        TestCase::$databaseMigrated = true;
    }
}
```

But does anybody have idea how to detect last test ?

```
protected function tearDown()
{
    // something here ? ?
}
```

Comment: Look at setUpBeforeClass() and tearDownAfterClass

Comment: tearDownAfterClass is called for each test class

Comment: And you want to know the very last test, from all suites?

Comment: look at my answer, it is solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

```
public static $databaseMigrated = false;

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    if (TestCase::$databaseMigrated === false) {
        TestCase::$databaseMigrated = true;
        register_shutdown_function(function(){
            //register wanted code here
        });
    });
}
```