# How to wrap whole class in transaction in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

My idea is to specify in each test class parameters, depends how we want to wrap test in transactions. I use Laravel 5.1.

```
use DB;

class TestCase
{
    protected static $wrapMethodInTransaction = true;
    protected static $wrapClassInTransaction = false;

    /**
     * @beforeClass
     */
    public static function isClassWrappedInTransactionBefore()
    {
        if (!static::$wrapMethodInTransaction && static::$wrapClassInTransaction) {
            DB::beginTransaction();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @afterClass
     */
    public static function isClassWrappedInTransactionAfter()
    {
       if (!static::$wrapMethodInTransaction && static::$wrapClassInTransaction) {
            DB::rollback();
       }
    }
}
```

The case is that `@beforeClass` & `@afterClass` fires when application is not booted yet/already dead, thus class `DB` is not accesible. I just want to run those methods once per class, but when application is booted/not killed yet. Are there any solutions for this?

`DatabaseTransactions` trait does not do the work, because it starts transaction after `setUp()` and rollbacks it after `tearDown()`. Laravel's 'magic'. I want the `setUp()` to be in transaction.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I use Laravel 5.1

Comment: You might find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485223/how-to-detect-last-test-from-testcase-in-laravel